# Plot Dicom data in sagittal and coronal plane with "slicelocation" in stead of slice number in python

Tags: python, numpy, medical-imaging, d3dimage

I'm currently using this code to plot my dicom data in all planes:

```
for i, s in enumerate(slices):
    img2d = s.pixel_array
    img3d[:, :, i] = img2d
```

However, you need to set aspects of the axis to plot the correct scale of the images.
I want to change the values of "i" to the values of "s.SliceLocation"

Something like this:

```
for i, s in slices:
    img2d = s.pixel_array
    slices = s.slicelocations
    img3d[:, :, i] = img2d, slices(i)
```

I tried different methods but it keeps giving me errors like:

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Or that the first column is filled with the values of slicelocation.

Can someone help me to figure this out?